# Scala 3 TypeRepr match on higher-kinded type

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

How do I properly pattern match a `TypeRepr` on a higher-kinded type? Existentials successfully match for classes, but when I try with a type I get the compiler error `unreducible application of higher-kinded type writetype.Foo to wildcard arguments`

```
import scala.quoted.*

type Foo[X]
class Bar[X]

inline def writeType[T]: String = ${writeTypeImpl[T]}

def writeTypeImpl[T](using Type[T], Quotes): Expr[String] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  val tpe = TypeRepr.of[T]
  val s = tpe.asType match
    //case '[Foo[?]] => "FooSuccess"
    case '[Bar[?]] => "BarSuccess"
    case _ => "Fail"

  Expr(s)
```

Comment: This works with `type Foo[X] = Bar[X]` for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer you need :

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-other-changes.html#wildcard-type-argument

You have to use a `trait` or `abstract class` or `Foo[A]` where is a concrete type (or type parameter)

Comment: Ah this comment in the docs does appear to apply. I wish the docs said a bit about why the compiler doesn't like it since it doesn't seem like an unsound construction. I don't have control over the specifics of `Foo` in my real case, so maybe the best solution is to try to match on `tpe.typeSymbol.fullname` first. Not ideal, but preferable in this case to the wrapping solution suggested in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

> @smarter:
>
> This is intentionally not supported: we only allow wildcards on class types (because anything else would be equivalent to existential types which we don't support)

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/9897

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/5302

https://users.scala-lang.org/t/solved-unreducible-application-of-higher-kinded-type-to-wildcard-arguments/7257

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html

You can match `'[Foo[t]]`

```
case '[Foo[t]] => "FooSuccess"
case '[Bar[_]] => "BarSuccess"
case _         => "Fail"
```

but this doesn't work with abstract types as expected

```
writeType[Bar[Int]] // BarSuccess
writeType[Bar[?]]   // BarSuccess
writeType[Foo[Int]] // Fail
```